# OpenGL handling re-sizing the window

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, viewport, orthographic

Writing a small opengl application that creates an orthographic projection with the camera at 0,0,0 looking towards -1. I am having some difficulties wrapping my head around resizing the window while keeping things looking decent.

```
vmathP3MakeFromElems(&eye, 0, 0, 0);
vmathP3MakeFromElems(&center, 0, 0, -1);
vmathV3MakeFromElems(&up, 0, 1, 0);

vmathM4MakeLookAt(&v_mat, &center, &eye, &up);

vmathV3MakeFromElems(&t_trans, (width * 0.5), (height * 0.5), -20.0);
vmathM4MakeTranslation(&v_mat, &t_trans);

vmathM4MakeOrthographic(&p_mat, 0, width, 0, height, 1.0, 100.0);
float aspect = width / height;
```

after I create the view matrix looking at 0,0, -1 then I translate it so that 0,0 is the center of the screen. That works just fine. When I draw something at 0,0 it's where it's suppose to be.

When the window is re-sized if I do something like updating the projection matrix with the new size and re-centering the view using the code above, like this:

```
resize(int width, int height) {
    vmathP3MakeFromElems(&eye, 0, 0, 0);
    vmathP3MakeFromElems(&center, 0, 0, -1);
    vmathV3MakeFromElems(&up, 0, 1, 0);

    vmathM4MakeLookAt(&v_mat, &center, &eye, &up);

    vmathV3MakeFromElems(&t_trans, (width * 0.5), (height * 0.5), -20.0);
    vmathM4MakeTranslation(&v_mat, &t_trans);

    vmathM4MakeOrthographic(&p_mat, 0, width, 0, height, 1.0, 100.0);
    float aspect = width / height;
}
```

then what happens is if I stretch the width the image's width gets squashed. If I stretch the height the images height gets squashed.

If I shrink the width, then the image's width gets wider and if I shrink the height, the image gets shorter.

How can I adjust this behavior to say cap the height at a specific height and show more width or cap the width and make the height get taller?